# How to test a controller function with argument form?

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, junit, controller

Heads Up: It is my first post here, please excuse any missing information or the really novice questions.

So I am currently trying to write jUnit tests for the already finished web application that uses spring (everything works, I just have to get full coverage with the tests). 
I have the classes: "Employee", "EmployeeController" and "EmployeeManagement".
I want to test the "registerNew" function which creates a new Employee with the filled form "EmployeeRegistrationForm" if it has no errors ("Errors result").

Now I want to write a Test for this to make sure that the function really does create a new object "Employee" which should be saved in the "EmployeeRepository" with said form.

However, I cannot seem to be able to create a filled "EmployeeForm" since it is abstract and cannot be instantiated. Therefore I am struggling to give any argument to that  function and do not know how to pass the information needed for the test to function being tested.

```
@Service

@Transactional

public class EmployeeManagement {

    private final EmployeeRepository employees;
    private final UserAccountManager userAccounts;


    EmployeeManagement(EmployeeRepository employees, UserAccountManager userAccounts) {

        Assert.notNull(employees, "employeeRepository must not be null!");
        Assert.notNull(userAccounts, "UserAccountManager must not be null!");

        this.employees=employees;
        this.userAccounts = userAccounts;
    }

    //the function that creates the employee
    public Employee createEmployee(EmployeeRegistrationForm form) {

        Assert.notNull(form, "Registration form must not be null!");

        String type = form.getType();
        Role role = this.setRole(type);
        UserAccount useraccount = userAccounts.create(form.getUsername(), form.getPassword(), role);

        useraccount.setFirstname(form.getFirstname());
        useraccount.setLastname(form.getLastname());


        return employees.save(new Employee(form.getNumber(), form.getAddress(), useraccount));
    }

@Controller

public class EmployeeController {

    private final EmployeeManagement employeeManagement;

    EmployeeController(EmployeeManagement employeeManagement) {

        Assert.notNull(employeeManagement, "userManagement must not be null!");

        this.employeeManagement = employeeManagement;
    }

    @PostMapping("/registerEmployee")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    String registerNew(@Valid EmployeeRegistrationForm form, Errors result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registerEmployee";
        }

        employeeManagement.createEmployee(form);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
public interface EmployeeRegistrationForm {

    @NotEmpty(message = "{RegistrationForm.firstname.NotEmpty}")
    String getFirstname();

    @NotEmpty(message = "{RegistrationForm.lastname.NotEmpty}")
    String getLastname();


    @NotEmpty(message = "{RegistrationForm.password.NotEmpty}")
    String getPassword();

    @NotEmpty(message = "{RegistrationForm.address.NotEmpty}")
    String getAddress();

    @NotEmpty(message = "{RegistrationForm.number.NotEmpty}")
    String getNumber();

    @NotEmpty(message = "{RegistrationForm.type.NotEmpty}")
    String getType();

    @NotEmpty(message = "{RegistrationForm.username.NotEmpty}")
    String getUsername();
}
```

Comment: There would be some class extending in your application extending `EmployeeRegistrationForm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I cannot seem to be able to create a filled "EmployeeForm" **since it is abstract and cannot be instantiated**.

Use [Mockito](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all) to instantiate your abstract classes.
You can use it like this:

```
EmployeeForm form = mock(EmployeeForm.class);
```

Now you have an instance of `EmployeeForm` which you can pass to your methods. If you need to call some methods from your mock you can do somethifg like this:

```
given(form.getFirstname()).willReturn("John");
```

This way the form will behave the way you want.

Note: `mock()` comes from `org.mockito.Mockito` and `given` comes from `org.mockito.BDDMockito`.